# Update ICU extension within xampp?

Tags: php, xampp, icu, intl

I'm running `xampp` and I need to upgrade `ICU` (php_intl extension) to the latest version - I downloaded `54` from the ICU page but unsure how to go about upgrading it.

There is a `bin`, `include` and `lib` folder - where do I put these files and do I have to do anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To upgrade existing ICU in you XAMP installation you'll need to:

1. copy php_intl.dll to your_xamp_folder/php
2. copy all the icu*.dll files to your_xamp_folder/apache/bin
3. check if extension=php_intl.dll is enabled in your_xamp_folder/php/php.ini
4. restart Apache

Let me know if it works (i'm currently on nginx)

**Edit:**

- you'll find php_intl.dll [here](http://nebm.ist.utl.pt/~glopes/misc/intl_win/php_intl-3.0.0-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip)
- all icu*.dll files are [here](http://nebm.ist.utl.pt/~glopes/misc/intl_win/ICU-51.2-dlls.zip)

Comment: Shouldn't `php_int.dll` go in the `ext` dir? Also, `icu*.dll` files inside `xampp/apache/bin`? My current ones are in `xampp/php` - nothing in the `apache/bin` dir.

Comment: On this site (https://jumpifzero.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/intl-extension-missing-on-xampp/) you can find same locations. And it says to copy *from* php folder *to* apache folder. Did you tried it?

Comment: Well when I downloaded the ICU update from their site I got `icu` files with `54` in it; however in my current PHP dir I have `41, 42 & 46` files. So do I need to put the new `icu` files in both the apache and php dirs or what? Also, what about all the other files that were included in the download?

Comment: On [PECL intl page](http://pecl.php.net/package/intl) you can download  version as `ICU 51`. You need two things: `ICU` and `PHP` module compiled against **same** `ICU` version. From that page you can achieve `ICU 51`, i don't know how to get `PHP` binaries for version `54`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this extension has been included in PHP since version 5.3.

Try upgrading PHP, or pointing to a newer version in XAMPP.

If that isn't an option, installing extensions for PHP can be found here [Extensions on Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php)
The php.net docs seem to cover [Installing INTL](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php)

It looks like you will need to point to your extension in php.ini

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I know it's included, but the version I have is too old and I want to update it to support new features. I am running PHP `5.4.4` and don't want ti upgrade to 5.5 at the moment. Those links tell me how to install it, I need to know how to *upgrade* it and if upgrading it is possible without upgrading your version of PHP (compatibility etc).

Comment: @Brett Download latest php realease from http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/. Unzip it, go in /ext/ dir and copy php_intl.dll. Paste in  your /xampp/php/ext/ and try.

Comment: @SimoneNigro What about all the `icu*.dll` files? Don't they need to be updated as well?