# intl extension with given ICU version for Symfony 3 with PHP 7.1

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have installed Symfony 3.2.6. When i check /config.php in browser i get a message:

> intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated (57.1) and does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (58.2)
>   To get the latest internationalization data upgrade the ICU system package and the intl PHP extension.

First a tried to update ICU extensions like it was described here [Update ICU extension within xampp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395844/update-icu-extension-within-xampp)
I downloaded suitable package from PECL http://site.icu-project.org/download/58 coppied to apache/bin folder, restarted apache, but PHP loads the old 57.1 ICU version.

Then I tried to update php_intl.dll ftom https://pecl.php.net/package/intl but i didn't find any suitable package for php 7.

Is there a proper wat to uprgrade ICU lib in php 7?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43014825/2359679

Comment: This is kind of a nasty problem. All current php 7 versions are using ICU version 57.x. I think it does not make a difference to change the dll files because the reference is part of the php_intl.dll.

Answer (score 3):

That's a really nasty problem. If there is no newer compatible PHP version and since updating the intl extensions did not do to the trick I guess you have to compile PHP with a custom ICU version:

The ICU versions can be checked out here: http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/tags/

```
Check out
cd source
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/../build (sets a custom install dir)
make (build)
make install (install to "build" dir)
```

Now that ICU is built, you need to run PHP's "configure" script and point it to the build dir:

```
./configure ... --enable-intl --with-icu-dir=/path/to/icu/build
```